# While data inserting table are view in ssis. How to set commit value?

Tags: ssis

How to set commit size while moving data from a flat file to a VIEW (Table or View)?

I have imported 12 million records used this method in SSIS 2005 version. I got below error. [image]

Comment: What do you mean "my question is how to commit"?

Comment: Are you looking for the [batch size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141239(v=sql.90).aspx) in the SSIS bulk insert task?

Comment: How to give commit size for view "Table or View" destination.

Comment: Your question is confusing and has many grammar mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an OLE DB Destination component.  Set the Data access mode to Table or View - Fast Load.  Ten you can set the Maximum insert commit size.

Comment: I'm got error in Table or View fast load my team architec suggest Table or View load.